# i could not use Auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, autolayout

I have `xib` file as below. It has `UIImageView`, `UITableView` and Two `UIView`s(containers) which consist of two `button`s. Sometimes my `tableView` has data to fill `tableRows` and sometimes not. if there is not data to fill `tableView`, i must hide it. When i remove `tableView`, my two containers should be appear in its place. How can i do this? thanks.

my `xib` file looks like this picture:

[image]

Comment: r u tried with auto layout? if yes then what u tried?

Comment: even i dont know what to try

Comment: Can explain your question little bit more so someone can give you better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if do you know autolayout than you can do it easily to creating some layout constraint so according to your condition to follow following process to add constraint to your subviews to superview

1. add leading,top,trailing to imageview.
2. add leading,top,trailing to your tableview and vertical spacing between imageview and your tableview
3. create a height constraint of tableview and make a iboutlet of it. it's value can be manage programmatic when you do not have data then set o to it's height constraint otherwise put it as it is.
4. add leading, top, trailing to your save's view and add vertical spacing between tableview and your save's view.
5. add leading, top, trailing to your like's view and add vertical spacing between save's view and like's view. add bottom spacing to like's view

Answer (score 1):

Just set the autoresizing mask as the attached image for both container views.

[image: Set autoresizing as this]

Comment: if i do this, `container` covers `uiimageview`

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to understand the concept of Autolayout which will simply solve your problem.
Here you can find a nice tutorial

[Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

You can set a height constraint for the table view and also a vertical spacing between tableview to container 1, container 1 to container 2. Then you can set the height constraint to 0 whenever there is no data. So the views automatically get moved

**Note :** You need to set other relative constraints also. You will get a knowledge about that after take a look on the above tutorial